# How can I get the extension(s) of a file based on its content?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, mime-types

I'm planning on downloading a bunch of images from a website that don't come with an extension, so I want to add one based on the file's content or mime-type.

`file <filename>` does a great job at identifying the filetype, however I need the extension.

```
--extension
      Print a slash-separated list of valid extensions for the file type found.
```

This is from `file`'s man page, but it does not seem to work:

```
$ file --extension test_text_file.txt
test_text_file.txt: ???

$ file --extension test_png_file.png
test_png_file.png: ???

$ file --extension test_gif_file.gif
test_gif_file.gif: ???
```

It literally prints `???` for every file I pass to it, even those that already have a proper extension. All of these are valid files of their types and get recognized perfectly by `file` without `--extension`.

Why does `file --extension` not work for me and what can I use to get a file's extension?

An idea would be to use `file --mime-type` and then create a dispatch table array that maps known mime-types to their extensions, but I'd much rather have a simpler and safer solution.

Comment: I’m assuming you have tried removing the extension from the file name and then ran `file` against it?

Comment: Yes. The output is the same `???` for every file.

Comment: What is your version of file?  file --version

Comment: @cybernard `file-5.33`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `file --extension` not work for me?

Not only for you. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440844/108618). One of the comments there seems right:

> Maybe just a very, very incomplete feature?

I haven't found any standard Unix tool to do the conversion, so your idea may be the easiest solution anyway.

> An idea would be to use `file --mime-type` and then create a dispatch table array that maps known mime-types to their extensions, but I'd much rather have a simpler and safer solution.

Note such a map exists, it's `/etc/mime.types`. See [this another question on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86349/108618). Based on one of the answers I came up with the following function:

```
function getext() {
   [ "$#" != 1 ] && { echo "Wrong number of arguments. Provide exactly one." >&2; return 254; }
   [ -r "$1" ] || { echo "Not a file, nonexistent or unreadable." >&2; return 1; }
   grep "^$(file -b --mime-type "$1")"$'\t' /etc/mime.types |
      awk -F '\t+' '{print $2}'
}
```

Usage:

```
getext test_text_file.txt   # it takes just one argument
```

Tailor it to your needs, make it a script etc. The main concerns:

- If succeeded (exit status `0`), the output may be non-empty or empty (not even `\n`).
- Some mime-types return more than one extension. You can use `cut -d ' ' -f 1` to get at most one, it may not be the one you want though.
- So a custom map file instead of `/etc/mime.types` may be useful. This command will show you which mime-types exist in the current directory (and subdirectories):

  ```
  find . -type f -exec file -b --mime-type {} + | sort | uniq
  ```
- `grep` shouldn't match more than once (at least with `/etc/mime.types`); `^` (line start) and `$'\t'` (tab) are there to avoid partial matching. Use `grep -m 1 ...` (or `head -n 1` later) to be sure you'll get at most one line.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this great answer and the hint to `/etc/mime.types`, this works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning I think, it shows extension for a few file types

```
file --preserve-date --special-files --extension *
```

Result:

```
BMP_file:          ???
CPP_file:          ???
FIFO_file:         ERROR: (null)
GZ_file:           ???
HAR_file:          ???
H_file:            ???
HTML_file:         ???
JAR_file:          zip/cbz
JAVA_CLASS_file:   ???
JAVA_JAVA_file:    ???
JPG_file:          jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif
MKV_file:          ???
MP3_file:          ???
MP4_file:          ???
ODT_file:          ???
PDF_file:          ???
PNG_file:          ???
PPS_file:          ???
SHELL_SCRIPT_file: ???
SO_file:           ???
TIFF_file:         ???
TMP_file_GBQcW:    ???
XML_file:          ???
ZIP_file:          zip/cbz
```